# Can you still get gold skulltulas from soil after planting a magic bean?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I didn't realize that some (most? all?) soil has golden skulltulas hidden if you drop bugs in there. I've already planted magic beans in a bunch of places. If I've planted a magic bean in a place where a golden skulltula can be found, would I still be able to get that skulltula or is it lost forever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should still be able to get the Skulltulas after planting the magic beans.

http://zeldawiki.org/Magic_Bean

> Even though planting Magic Beans in soil will help gain access to
>   different areas, there is another use for the soil. Link can bottle
>   some Bugs and drop them into the soil. This will result in a Gold
>   Skulltula jumping out.[6][7] **This can be done even after a bean is
>   planted**.

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it, too. This game has proven good at ensuring you never get "stuck" to the point where you cannot go back and complete something.